# Docker /vfs folder size

Tags: docker

I have a problem with my docker.
I've downloaded an image, and docker shows its size about 600Mb.
But on the disk, in the /usr/lib/docker/ its using like almost 6Gb.

Here is my folder before image pull:

```
                         /..
   27.9 MiB [##########] /tmp
  236.0 KiB [          ] /image
   60.0 KiB [          ] /network
    8.0 KiB [          ] /vfs
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /volumes
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /trust
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /containers
```

And here is after image pull:

```
                         /..
    5.8 GiB [##########] /vfs
   27.9 MiB [          ] /tmp
    2.2 MiB [          ] /image
   60.0 KiB [          ] /network
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /volumes
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /trust
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /containers
```

Image itself:

```
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker.io/bitnami/mariadb   latest              f5dbed792113        8 days ago          598.1 MB
```

And its history:

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
f5dbed792113        8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/run.sh"]               0 B
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENTRYPOINT &{["/app-entrypo   0 B
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE 3306/tcp               0 B
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) VOLUME [/bitnami/mariadb]     0 B
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=no   0 B
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:c5bea93fb9ce36dc47   3.758 kB
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c bitnami-pkg unpack mariadb-10.1.23   482.1 MB
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c install_packages libaio1 libc6 lib   12.29 MB
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL maintainer=Bitnami <c   0 B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENTRYPOINT &{["/entrypoint.   0 B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:21a422cab8e9367936   10.17 kB
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV BITNAMI_IMAGE_VERSION=j   0 B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV PATH=/opt/bitnami/nami/   0 B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c cd /tmp &&   gpg --keyserver hkp:/   1.423 MB
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV GOSU_VERSION=1.10 GOSU_   0 B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c cd /tmp &&   gpg --keyserver hkp:/   40.76 kB
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV TINI_VERSION=v0.13.2      0 B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c cd /tmp &&   curl -sSLO https://na   16.77 MB
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV NAMI_VERSION=0.0.6-0      0 B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c install_packages curl ca-certifica   34.3 MB
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL maintainer=Bitnami <c   0 B
<missing>           3 weeks ago                                                         51.14 MB            from Bitnami with love
```

I'm new to the Docker, so is this normal?
I'm find that quite insane. Whole linux VM might be smaller, than this mariadb image.
How i can resolve this?
My docker info:

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.10.3
Storage Driver: vfs
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: journald
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 2.6.32-042stab120.20
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 2
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 512 MiB
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Registries: docker.io (secure)
```

Comment: For me it only raise 600MB on disk: `3.4G /var/lib/docker/aufs` -> `4.0G /var/lib/docker/aufs`. Your docker 1.10 is a bit old version

Comment: You see? This is weird.  Yes, i know, but this version is latest, that my VPS provider supports.

Comment: And I have no vfs directory

Comment: Thats because you have aufs as a storage driver.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `vfs` storage driver.

Quoting [Storage Drivers in Docker: A Deep Dive](https://integratedcode.us/2016/08/30/storage-drivers-in-docker-a-deep-dive/)

> First, let’s get the one special graphdriver out of the way–vfs is the
>   “naive” implementation of the interface that does not use a union
>   filesystem or CoW techniques at all, but rather **copies all the layers**
>   in order into a static subdirectory and mounts the end result as the
>   container root filesystem. It is not meant for real (production) use
>   but is very valuable for simple validation and testing of other parts
>   of the Docker engine.

My advise is to upgrade to the latest CentOS 7.2 to obtain the latest kernel version they support and use overlay2:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/

Comment: I still don't understand why 600MB download becomes 5.8GB on disk, despite the implementation

Comment: I get it. Thanks Ricardo! Will try for myself to see it.

Comment: If some initial layer is 600MB, 10 layers become almost 6GB. vfs doesn't implement CoW. The filesystems that implement CoW don't copy the whole previous layer but only the files and directories that change with each Dockerfile instruction. Get it?

Answer (score 0):

With [VFS storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/vfs-driver/) each RUN/COPY/ADD instruction in Dockerfile creates a full copy of image's filesystem during image build. So, if your Dockerfile file contains ten RUNs, it will create ten layers/copies.

The solution to this is to reduce the number of RUN/COPY/ADD instructions or to use other drivers (e.g. [Overlay2](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/)) that copy only changed files..

---

Also the final number of layers can be reduced by using instructions below at the end of Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
COPY --from=0 / /
```

It causes that all layers created before the `FROM scratch` instruction can be forgotten and freed (with `docker image prune`). What `COPY` does, refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/), it basically copy all files from one stage to new one.

You can check this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mediagis/nominatim-docker/blob/master/4.1/Dockerfile) for usage example.